# While installing Node.JS forever NPM package, it errors out on git:// address dependency

Tags: node.js, npm

I get the following error while trying to install forever (`sudo npm install forever -g`):

```
npm info bundling for forever@0.8.2 [ 'git://github.com/bmeck/node-fork.git' ]
npm ERR! Doesn't exist: git://github.com/bmeck/node-fork.git
npm ERR! Error installing git://github.com/bmeck/node-fork.git
npm ERR! install failed Error: ENOENT, No such file or directory 'git://github.com/bmeck/node-fork.git'
npm info install failed rollback
```

I realized I didn't have git-core installed, so I apt-got it, and was able to clone from that git address. Is there something else I'm forgetting?

Comment: Try to use `-d` flag for `npm` to see debug messages. This will produce more information on what's going on...

Comment: What is your npm version? `npm -v` prints it.

Comment: version: 0.2.19 -- I'll upgrade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out I was running an older version of NPM (0.2.19) upgraded using: `curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh`

and `sudo npm install forever -g` worked